# How to use the RatingBar in Android properly?

Tags: android, ratingbar

Need some help with implementing/understanding how the RatingBar works.

In my Activity I inflate my xml which has a RatingBar in it multiple times. Something like this. Stripped out version is

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

View contentView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
setContentView(contentView);
// there are other views here sooo had to do it this way.
ViewGroup ratingsContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.x11);
for(int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++){
    ratingsContainer.addView(createRatingBar(i)); 
}
}

private RatingBar createRatingBar(int index){
    RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ratingbar, null);
    ratingBar.setRating(index);
    return ratingBar;
}
```

My ratingbar xml

```
<RatingBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:stepSize="1"/>
```

my activity_main

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/x11"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    </LinearLayout>    
    </LinearLayout>
```

But it does not seem to work properly
1. The number of stars it shows is more than the number of stars. More than 5
2. The data does not hold on rotation.

What do you think might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. The number of stars it shows is more than the number of stars. More than 5

Quote from the documentation:

> The number of stars set (via setNumStars(int) or in an XML layout)
>   will be shown when the layout width is set to wrap content (if another
>   layout width is set, the results may be unpredictable).

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html

> 1. The data does not hold on rotation.

When you rotate the screen, the `onCreate` method is called, recreating them. You can either use onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstance state to save/restore the ratings, or you can add them via XML in your `activity_main.xml` file and let Android do that for you.

EDIT:
The problem with the width was related with using `null` when inflating the `layout`.
To fix it:

```
ViewGroup ratingsContainer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // there are other views here sooo had to do it this way.
        ratingsContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.x11);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            ratingsContainer.addView(createRatingBar(i));
        }
    }

    private RatingBar createRatingBar(int index) {
        RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.ratingbar, ratingsContainer, false);
        ratingBar.setRating(index);
        return ratingBar;
    }
```

More info about why you shouldn't use `null` when inflating [here](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/).

For your second problem (rotation):
You can put the RatingBars in the `activity_main` file, eliminating the need for `createRatingBar` function.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/x11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rb1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:stepSize="1" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rb2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:stepSize="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: As you can see the layout_width is set to wrap_content. So I dont know why you would say that. Second, I also have a text view there which manages to hold on to its data. Evevery time onCreate is called I fill up the data again. I dont need to do anything else.

Comment: can you post your `activity_main.xml` layout?

Comment: This did not resolve it. But that was nice to know. Your rotation solution I can't use RatingBar like that. The for loop has a 5 there. can sometimes have 2 can sometimes have 10 so I need to inflate that view the same way.

Comment: then you can override `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstance` to save/restore the values. The system does it automatically for views inflated via XML.

Comment: Or you can try adding an ID to the rating bar (int value grater than 0) by calling `setId`

Comment: ALthough your solution did not help me it was nice to read the inflating part plus you tried to help me out a lot. Thanks :) It will definitely help me out in the future. I figured the problem out, basically the Rating bar saves the values, setting it to false solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

> The data does not hold on rotation.

This is because the Activity/the fragment is created new, when the orientation changes. You have to store the state - there are many good answers around the www. One is this:
[Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android)

Comment: If its created new I am still repopulating it with the data; as you can see. Oncreate is called onRotation as well. So I dont see the problem

Comment: Repopulating it might not be the best approach, as soon as the user interacts with it.

Comment: Its the small style so users cant interact with it.